# How to find original implementation of a method when multiple method swizzling

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, method-swizzling

e.g. if origin IMP is `UIViewController - ViewDidLoad`

In my project, may like `main Project` + `many other SDK(frameworks)`, if other team member swizzling the same method, like `UIViewController - ViewDidLoad`, and i how to make sure or how to find out the origin IMP of `ViewDidLoad` to swilling? cause the other team member also need to swilling the same method?

Comment: Swizzling `+viewDidLoad` is a very very bad idea.   Swizzling it multiple times across multiple frameworks is even worse.   You can *likely* figure out the original implementation by determine the address of the IMP and then figuring out which mach-o it came from, but that's a whole lot of tedious hair pulling to support an untenable implementation pattern.

Comment: @bbum yes, Swizzling `ViewDidLoad` just an example, i just want to know how to make sure or how to find out the origin IMP when multiple method swizzling